# SWT - asyncExec directing output to List widget

Tags: java, list, swt, java-threads

I am trying to use the Display.asyncExec() method to print status updates to a SWT List widget as they are generated, instead of having the updates dumped to the List when the program finishes.  I keep getting a java.lang.NullPointerException. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  The program was working fine until I tried to use separate threads and use the Display.asyncExec method.  Any suggestions appreciated.

The error: " Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-0" "

My CustomOutputStream class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;

/**
This class extends from OutputStream to redirect output to a SWT List widget
**/
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private List list;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private Runnable runnable;

    public CustomOutputStream(List list) {
        this.list = list;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {    
        // redirects data to the text area upon newline character
        if(String.valueOf((char)b).equals("\n") ){    
            list.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(!list.isDisposed() ) {           
                        // redirects data to the text area
                        list.add(sb.toString());
                        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
                        list.select(list.getItemCount() - 1);
                        list.showSelection();
                        list.deselectAll();
                    }                   
                }           
            });
            runnable.run();
            sb.setLength(0);
        }
        else{
            sb.append(String.valueOf((char)b)); 
        }
    }

}
```

In my DVS class:

```
public class DVS implements Runnable{
    private PrintStream log;
    // constructor
    public DVS( CustomOutputStream LOG) {
        log = new PrintStream(LOG);
        run();
    }
    public void run() {
         System.setOut(log);
         System.setErr(log);
         /**  
         code that invokes System.out.println() ....
         **/
    }
}
```

In my main class:

```
Public List list = new List(shell, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
Public CustomOutputStream log = new CustomOutputStream(list);
DVS algo = new DVS(log);
Thread thread = new Thread(algo);
thread.start();
```

Comment: Might be helpful to post the stack trace for your NullPointerException.

Comment: It was :Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-0"

Comment: @JoeO'Neill The **full** stack trace would be helpful. Please add it to your question and not a comment btw.

Comment: That was the full stack trace, in its entirety.  There was no other error information given.  I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any place where `runnable` is initialized, so it will be `null` when you try to call `runnable.run()`.

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    // ...
    private Runnable runnable;

    public CustomOutputStream(List list) {
        this.list = list;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {    
        if(String.valueOf((char)b).equals("\n") ){    
            // ...
            runnable.run();
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }

}
```